# Installing no longer existing files

Tags: cmake, installation

I have a list of various files that I want to install, by executing a resulting `INSTALL` project. This works, but sometimes files are no longer available, when the install operation is executed. Environment is a build server, where files get moved around -> this causes the build to be faulty.

An easy way to fix this behaviour is in the `OPTIONAL` parameter of the install command. So my question is: Is there a way to output warnings at runtime, if the install command failed?

Here is my code, to recreate the issue. In the `src` directory there are files "1.txt" and "2.txt". I build the cmakelists.txt and then delete "2.txt". After that, I execute the `INSTALL` solution I got.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(documentation)

set(SOURCEDOCUMENTATION "D:/projects/side_master/src/documentation/src")
set(TARGETDOCUMENTATION "D:/projects/side_master/src/documentation/tgt")

file (GLOB files_to_install "${SOURCEDOCUMENTATION}/*")

foreach(file_to_install ${files_to_install})
      install(FILES ${file_to_install} DESTINATION ${TARGETDOCUMENTATION} OPTIONAL)
endforeach()
```

The error (without the `OPTIONAL` parameter):

```
-- Install configuration: "Debug"
-- Installing: D:/projects/side_master/src/documentation/tgt/1.txt
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:56 (file):
    file INSTALL cannot find
    "D:/projects/side_master/src/documentation/src/2.txt".
```

What I want to get is a generated message, like this:

```
File "D:/projects/side_master/src/documentation/src/2.txt" not found.
```

Comment: Perhaps, you can use the `install(SCRIPT ...)` or [`install(CODE ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#custom-installation-logic) command to run custom CMake install steps checking for the existence of these files (using `if(EXISTS ...)` logic) and printing a warning if they do not?

Comment: Yes, this works:

`install(CODE "if (EXISTS ${file_to_install}) else() MESSAGE(\"File ${file_to_install} not found.\") endif()")`

If you write it as an answer, I'll up it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the `install(SCRIPT ...)` or [`install(CODE ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#custom-installation-logic) signatures of the CMake `install` command, to run custom installation steps specific to your use case. The custom steps here would check for the existence of the files (using CMake's [`EXISTS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#condition-syntax) logic) to be installed, and print a warning message if the file does not exist. The custom installation command could look something like this:

```
install(CODE "
    if(NOT EXISTS ${file_to_install})
        message(WARNING \"File ${file_to_install} not found during installation.\")
    endif()
")
```